# Unable to use script to send email, when cell with complex GoogleFinance function changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I have a formula in Google Spreadsheet (Cell G4):

`=AVERAGE(INDEX( GoogleFinance(B4  , "all" , WORKDAY( TODAY(), -50 ) , TODAY() ) , , 3))`

where, B4=INDEXBOM:SENSEX

I am trying to use following script to send email when cell value changes:

```html
function checkValue()    
{ 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("G4").getValue();

  if(valueToCheck > 10000)  
    {
      MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Subject", "Context" + valueToCheck+ ".");
    }  

}
```

I set up time driven trigger to automatically run the script every hour. However, script does not send email.

After debugging, I found that since above function takes some time to calculate, valueToCheck output is a string ("#REF!") instead of a number.

Is there a way to work with this? I already tried using Utilities.sleep function to allow spreadsheet to finish calculation before script is executed but I am not successful with it.

I also tried using SpreadsheetApp.flush() but it didn't help as well.

I am not a programmer and have got stuck here. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect following statement given in [GoogleFinance function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) document could be the reason:

> Historical data cannot be downloaded or accessed via the Sheets API or Apps Script.  If you attempt to do so, you will see a #N/A error in place of the values in the corresponding cells of your spreadsheet.